# Is it possible to create custom npm run commands for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, csv, command, npm-run

Laravel has the following built-in `npm run` commands (among others):

```
npm run install
npm run watch
```

Is it possible to create custom `npm run` commands to run custom PHP scripts? For example, I want to create a command called `npm run csv` that will run a PHP script that imports a bunch of CSV data into a database.

Thanks.

---

**Edit**: After asking the question and seeing a lot of the responses, it has become overwhelming obvious that writing a `php artisan` command is probably the better way to go. As such, that's what I will do.

Thank you all for your responses. As for why I didn't ask that question, it's quite simple: I didn't know that that was a better approach. I'm still new to Laravel and learning. Thanks.

Comment: why even bother with npm? just make a PHP executable

Comment: Why would you want to use npm for this? Couldn't the Laravel command system be used for this?

Comment: Scripts are defined in `package.json`, might want to take a look there

Comment: Fair enough. Could you guys be more specific in your recommendation? Where do I define the command and how do I execute it? `php artisan`?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan is worth a read

Comment: Good link, kerbholz. Thanks.

Comment: I use the symfony/console component now. My answer below is what i was doing before i started doing that. If you are comfortable working with the Laravel command system however, I'd recommend that over my solution below

Comment: Was hard to chose a single best answer, as all of the answers helped. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, you must write [Artisan Console Command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#writing-commands). Then you could run it using `npm`. But this is not a recommended way. you can run any artisan command like:

```
php artisan inspire
```

If you want to run this with `npm` just add this command in the `package.json`'s script. For example:

```
{
   "scripts": {
       "inspire": "php artisan inspire"
   }
}
```

Then run the command like this:

```
npm run inspire
```

Comment: Which file does this go into?

Comment: in `package.json` file.

Comment: why type `npm run inspire` though when you could easily just type `php artisan inspire`? It seems very odd to add an extra layer for no good reason, or am i missing something?

Comment: Agree @delboy1978uk. But that's what @ HartleySan want. I also don't recommend this.

Comment: In my case I have to run php artisan before npm so inside package.json you can concat scripts easily->  "dev": "php artisan vue-i18n:generate && npm run development

Answer (score 3):

It should be cleaner to create your own artisan command.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#writing-commands

Then put your csv import code inside the handle() method.

You will just have to run : php artisan import-csv or something like

Answer (score 2):

I love this side of Laravel. From what you are trying to achieve, may I advise on custom artisan commands? :)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan

Recommend the reading, it is great for what you are looking :D

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use NPM to call PHP! Why not just create your own executable?

Using Laravel, there is a command system, so you can make your own `artisan` commands. But if you want something simpler, you can do this:

Example. I create a file in my project called `bin/do_stuff`

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
      echo "Easy as that!\n";
```

Then make it executable:

```
chmod +x bin/do_stuff
```

Then you can run it with `./bin/do_stuff`! Not hard at all! Now you can also pass arguments like so:

```
./bin/do_stuff--option1=value1 --option2
```

With or without values. To do this, we add the following:

```
foreach ($argv as $arg)
{
    preg_match('/\-\-(\w*)\=?(.+)?/', $arg, $value);
    if ($value && isset($value[1]) && $value[1])
    {
       $options[$value[1]] = isset($value[2]) ? $value[2] : null;
    }
}
```

Great for in cron jobs and back end stuff. Give it a try!